# Automated deployment in IBM i-Series using Aldon Version Tool

Tags: ibm-midrange

Currently we are following manual deployment for promoting changes from iSeries QA system to Production System through Aldon and we are planning to automate the deployment using Adlon tool.Is anyone knows how to automate deployment in IBM i-Series using Aldon Version Tool.

Comment: I've set up Aldon.  It is quite a bit more involved than "turn it on".  You have to decide on policies for approvals, overrides and such, then train everyone on how to use.

Answer (score 0):

Just turn it on...the Deployment guide should have a section, **Deploying Objects from Integration and QA**

> **Prerequisites**
>
> - Create at least one target definition with Accept deployments from environment
> - Define at least one deployment profile for the release with Deploy from environment set to ITG or QUA having with at least one target
>     definition.
> - The release option Deploy when promoting to ITG or Deploy when promoting to QUA must be set to Y, or to N with Allow override set to
>     Y.

In order to fully deploy the objects, you'll want to have the deployment sets created with **Last Auto-Start step = *INSTALL**